# How to import the contacts from a .vcf file with the use of intents in a service(not in activity)

Tags: android

I am able to import the contacts from a .vcf file when i do tat in activity but not possible in service , can anyone help me out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator + "Contacts.vcf";

intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

intent2.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(storage_path)),"text/x-vcard"); //storage path is path of your vcf file.

this.startActivity(intent2);
```

You need to add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to start the Activity from a service .

Comment: waw it really worked.... actully this was the problem to start activity from service....thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent1.setDataAndType(data, "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(intent1);
```